# What size rear hub will fit a Trek FX1?

Tags: hub, trek

I have a Trek FX1 and the rear hub size 135x5mm. I want to change the hub to 135x10mm; is that going to be a problem?

Also, my bike is v-brake system. If the hub I want to fit has a disc brake mount, will that work?

Comment: AFAIK, 135 mm hubs are 10 mm. 5 mm does not exist. Are you sure of  your data ? You can use V-brake with disc hub with no problem, provided you have a rim for rim brakes. In my opinion it is a good idea to use a disc-brake hub for a V-brake wheel, as you will be able to re-use it int the future if youo get a disc-brake bike.

Comment: Yeah i am sure about the Formula FM31 alloy, 135x5mm QR that’s from the web site of trek company, and thanks for the tip about the hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FM31 corresponds to the standard 135 mm hub definition. You can use any 135 mm hub, disc or not. 5 mm is the diameter of the skewer inside the hub.

Comment: Thanks all clear